# How can I make line clamp work on ipad safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

Here is the css code of the span:

```
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #111;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<span>
          After many, many months of researching, I finally found Dr. M, a very special woman and surgeon. I knew right away that she'd be my surgeon! She recommended me to get Motiva Implants, the softest and most gorgeous implant I had ever seen in my life! She chose Motiva Ergonomix 450cc full projection, and they are perfect to say the least. My breasts are so soft and squishy, they feel like real boobs! I'm really happy with my decision, my surgeon is a genius and Motiva
          <a href="#" class="show__more" tabindex="0">
            ...Mai mult
          </a>
        </span>
```

[Here is the visual description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYfkU.jpg)

On google chrome the problem doesn't persist and the span keeps up to 10 lines, doesn't show more lines like it does on ipad safari

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and how it all comes together?

Comment: yes, I have added it to the question